# Mongoose populate across 2 databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a `node app` that uses 2 databases. One is the the `Names` and the other for the rest of all the data.

I have this connection setup:

```
// DATABASE CONNECTION
var APP_DB_URI = config.APP_DB; // mongodb://localhost:27017/app_db
var app_DB = mongoose.createConnection(APP_DB_URI);
var name_DB = app_DB.useDb(config.NAME_DB); // 'name_db'
```

This connection is working properly.

There's also no problem upon saving data to both `app_db` and `names_db` working perfect.

But the problem is this: when I try to query let say the `Account` model and then populate the referenced `Name` model, the populate process returns `null`.

**Account** schema:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var field = {
     email: {type: String, unique: true},
     password: {type: String, select: false},
     name: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Name'},
 }

 var options = {
     id: false,
     versionKey: false
 }

 var schema = new Schema(field, options);
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', schema);
```

**Name** schema:

```
 'use strict';

 var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var field = {
     firstName: {type: String, required: true},
     middleName: {type: String, required: true},
     lastName: {type: String, required: true},
     suffix: {type: String, required: false,},
 }

 var options = {
     id: false,
     versionKey: false
 }

 var schema = new Schema(field, options);
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Name', schema);
```

The query and population:

```
var app_db = *app_db instance passed to this controller*    

var Account = app_db.model('Account');

Account.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    .populate('name')
    .exec(function (err, user) {
        if(user){
            // user.name returns null
        }
    })
```

Is there a special way to populate data from db1 the data from db2? Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the revision

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Populate Mongo documents across databases](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2137) feature added since `mongoose v3.9.0`. Per this [across db populate test](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/91347cf80271fc968ab385f179858132e177eec3/test/model.populate.test.js#L129-160), you should different db name when `model` is called. Some sample codes as below. More details please refer to the test codes in the link.

```
var app_DB = mongoose.createConnection(APP_DB_URI);
var name_DB = app_DB.useDb(config.NAME_DB); // 'name_db'

// ...
module.exports = app_DB.model('Account', schema);

// ...
module.exports = name_DB.model('Name', schema);
```

**Populate**

```
.populate('name', '', Name)
```

Comment: I did exactly the same. But the populate still dont work.

Comment: What params exactly should I put to `.populate()` after doing this?  `.populate('name')` is now working.

Comment: I got it. `.populate('name', '', Name)` first is the reference key, I dont understand what the 2nd param is so I just leave it `' '` then the 3rd is the reference model

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, Refer to this [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate), the second param is `[select] <Object, String> Field selection for the population query`

Comment: @CENT1PEDE the second param defines the fields you want to be selected from the referenced model. in my case its "firstname lastname" no commas

Comment: I've spent 2 hours trying everything to get this working and your solution worked @zangw - this should be explained on the Mongoose docs that you need to specify a Model if you're using useDb because it's not explained anywhere.