# mongoose $lookup across multiple databases?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is possible that use mongoose `$lookup` for using across multiple databases?
Do you have any idea about this matter?

I have a user DB that contains users info in users collection.
and another DB for user's comments.

Answer (score 0):

As [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) says about `$lookup`:

> Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the **same** database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing.

So no, **answering your question: it's not possible**.

But, as an addition, using Mongo exists [db.getSiblingDB()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278814/mongodb-cross-database-query) option.

Docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) where says:

> Used to return another database without modifying the db variable in the shell environment.

And you can check [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6480) that in Mongoose the method is called `useDb()`.

Docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-useDb) where says:

> Switches to a different database using the same connection pool.

So, this is not a `$lookup` but is an approach to have another Data Base data.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571934/13464279) answer uses `useDb` and `populate`, maybe it helps you.

Also for your purpose check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19474712/13464279) question too.